# Get protein monomers in an automated way

Tags: python, biopython

For a given set of protein structures in pdb format from the PDB database, I would like to find some automated way for checking whether each structure is monomer, dimer, trimer, etc, so I only get for each case the unit structure or monomer. I head about biopython, but I am not sure and wonder whether there are other approaches for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the first step is to get access to the PDB database.  I am not familiar with biopython, but from the documentation it looks like it only has built in database connectors for the following:

- ExPASy
- SCOP
- Entrez (and Pubmed) from the NCBI

Do you know how you would be connecting to the PDB database?